# TypeScript function overloading with generic types

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to create a higher order function that takes a callback function and returns an anonymous function which in turn returns the result of callback function. The returned anonymous function takes a parameter called number (n). I use this parameter as a condition for the type of result that is returned by the anonymous function. Basically if number is greater than 1 return an array of results of callback function else return the result of callback function. But I can't seem to get this function overloading definitions work with generic types.

```
export type ReturnedFunctionType<T> = {
  (): T
  (n: number): T[]
  (n?: number): T | T[]
}

export function higherOrderFn<T> (cb: () => T): ReturnedFunctionType<T> {
  return function (n = 1) {
    if (n === 1) {
      return cb()
    } else {
      return Array(n).fill(null).map(_ => cb())
    }
  }
}
```

The error says:

```
Type '(n?: number) => T | T[]' is not assignable to type 'ReturnedFunctionType<T>'.
  Type 'T | T[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
```

Can somebody explain me why can't I do this? Or how can I correctly type such function ?

Comment: It think the best option is "export type ReturnedFunctionType<T> = (n?: number) => T | T[];".

Comment: Yes it silents the error. But there should be a way I could know the exact type of the returned value depending on how I call the function, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to name your overloaded function. something like this should work

```js
export function higherOrderFn<T> (cb: () => T) {
  function foo(n?: 1): T
  function foo(n: number): T[]
  function foo(n?: number): T | T[]   
   function foo(n = 1) {
    if (n === 1) {
      return cb()
    } else {
      return Array(n).fill(null).map(_ => cb())
    }
  }
  return foo;
}

const foobar = higherOrderFn(() => {})
const foo1 = foobar() // return type void
const foo2 = foobar(1) // return type void
const foo3 = foobar(2) // return type void[]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=45&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAMwK4DsDGMCWEVwBaYDmewUA8lACakBiKAPACoB8cAFGgEYBc7AlHAC8rRgIDeAWABQcRKgzZcCCBDYoA-LwCMfXo2mzk6LDkQq1vFEgC2nUrriMA2gF0Dc44rOqNlm3agHRjgAH0dXWTh3DwVTZR8hOB04SRlIzAR2XEEcpPFoyKhgGCQoXC42PgKAXzhgABsAZ2AUgtkikrK4AEEoKABDAE81PgA6BEx6%20rUkKbHrfrA2AH0hVgq%20KrTZavddtI7SpRUAbml96TQcRvh4zn6oRIJiUgpqKDo2SrWU6q2rlA3bxaRJ3B7fAD0ELghy6MEGYBaADcIJhKJdrrcVAAmUEqe5QNjJKEw4pHODwxFwFFojGArEQADMeIgBLY2IEJNhuEpyNRlFc0mkQA)

Comment: @SagarAcharya can you accept the answer if this solves your problem